# How to show webpage on a url in a Windows Service Application in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-services

What I'm trying to achieve is that if someone visits a particular URL, it will show a webpage (some html). This is what I have created until now:

How would you be able to check the URL like `https://127.0.0.1/webpage` and then create the webpage?

```
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StringContent("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
            return response;
        }
    }
```